# What does $(y-c)^{*\beta}$ mean

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, optimization, symbolic-computation

I recently came across an equation which says:
$$\alpha_0+\alpha_1y^{*\beta_1}+\alpha_2\left(y-c\right)^{*\beta_2}+\alpha_3\left(y-1\right)^{*\beta_3}$$
$$=\alpha_0+\alpha_1y^{\beta_1}+\alpha_2\left(y-c\right)^{*\beta_2}-\alpha_3\left(1-y\right)^{\beta_3}$$
where all the parameters are real, $0<y<1$ and $0<c<1$

What does $(y-c)^{*\beta}$ mean? How is it different than $(y-c)^{\beta}$?

Is it that $\alpha_2\left(y-c\right)^{*\beta_2}$ is a piecewise function?

This was seen in [this literature on XGLD](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610911003681503#.VLC3P3vqXmM)

Comment: maybe by letting us know the context or where did you read it.

Comment: hi @Phicar, i have added the reference with a little more details. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See definition 1 (8) in page 4. Is a piecewise function and it is different because it remains in $\mathbb{R}$. Consider $\beta = 1/2,y=0,c=1$, then $(y-c)^{\beta}=(-1)^{1/2}=i$ but $(y-c)^{*\beta}=-|0-1|^{1/2}=-1$.